# Object won't delete from Databricks dashboard

Tags: databricks

I'm trying to create a dashboard in Databricks and would like to delete a table I've added.  If I click on the delete button (circled below) the table just turns red and does not delete.

How do I delete this table from the Dashboard?

[image]

Comment: Why not use Databricks SQL? Dashboards there are better

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Databricks SQL.  Do you mean a Databricks notebook using SQL?  The dashboard functionality has better features for generating reports with multiple charts/tables and with out the underlying queries.

Comment: I'm talking about Databricks SQL - select the SQL persona on the top left drop down in the panel on the left. https://docs.databricks.com/sql/get-started/concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to remove the object by going back to the source workbook and un-selecting the add-to-dashboard for that table/figure.

I'm still not sure why Databricks is not letting me delete this object using this interface.